# Writing an array of single dict to csv file that key, value becomes one row

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

When I run this code, the print statement prints the full object, but the csv writer only writes the first part to the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv

`testlabels = [{'585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c': '586556570100dac0eb73fcb231007126'}, {'585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8': '588b9329004c4d7a5e27eb75b43c4c95'}, {'585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779': '588be66300aba64caf9818cb4e194413'}, {'585ac23f005d7eab58953e03ae2e11e9': '588fe14100743d4472f8e18c474f057c'}, {'585ac23f005d7edd65e8c2bf4439dced': '58952dd60011750508739823983a1e33'}, {'585aca480065fa7ffb9e9b164bf03c82': '586557e201025a1d4818a0f5fe1b3051'}, {'585af09a0097e08d445c31bafc966c90': '585af0e300981a8493a172d6471b9154'}, {'585af1b60098bf1155b231a4d1c407f4': '58c0887600b478187ffbeb1d1db575d3'}, {'585af1b60098bf54b60bcab8c012ec1b': '58c0891900b4e2424cd148a3987bb899'}, {'585af1b60098bf8e26b6b27d44c17e01': '58c08af100b0dba976bab7f6866ca206'}]


resultFile = open("output.txt",'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile)

for item in testlabels:
    print(item)
    wr.writerow(item)
```

I have also tried:

```
wr.writerows(testlabels)
```

Output in stdout:

```
> {'585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c':  '586556570100dac0eb73fcb231007126'}
>{'585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8':'588b9329004c4d7a5e27eb75b43c4c95'}
> {'585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779':'588be66300aba64caf9818cb4e194413'}
> {'585ac23f005d7eab58953e03ae2e11e9':'588fe14100743d4472f8e18c474f057c'}
```

Output in file:

```
> 585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c 
> 585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8
> 585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779 
> 585ac23f005d7eab58953e03ae2e11e9
> 585ac23f005d7edd65e8c2bf4439dced 
> 585aca480065fa7ffb9e9b164bf03c82
> 585af09a0097e08d445c31bafc966c90 
> 585af1b60098bf1155b231a4d1c407f4
> 585af1b60098bf54b60bcab8c012ec1b 
> 585af1b60098bf8e26b6b27d44c17e01
```

Expected Output:

```
'585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c','586556570100dac0eb73fcb231007126'
'585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8','588b9329004c4d7a5e27eb75b43c4c95'
'585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779','588be66300aba64caf9818cb4e194413'
...
```

Comment: ***"What am I doing wrong?"***: The `items` in `testlabels` are of type `dict`. But `csv.writerrow...` expects a [sequence-type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range). You have to unpack it, e.g. **`item = list(item.items())[0]`**

Comment: the list method suggested by @stovfl worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using pandas you could

```py
import pandas as pd

testlabels = [{'585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c': '586556570100dac0eb73fcb231007126'},
              {'585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8': '588b9329004c4d7a5e27eb75b43c4c95'},
              {'585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779': '588be66300aba64caf9818cb4e194413'},
              {'585ac23f005d7eab58953e03ae2e11e9': '588fe14100743d4472f8e18c474f057c'},
              {'585ac23f005d7edd65e8c2bf4439dced': '58952dd60011750508739823983a1e33'},
              {'585aca480065fa7ffb9e9b164bf03c82': '586557e201025a1d4818a0f5fe1b3051'},
              {'585af09a0097e08d445c31bafc966c90': '585af0e300981a8493a172d6471b9154'},
              {'585af1b60098bf1155b231a4d1c407f4': '58c0887600b478187ffbeb1d1db575d3'},
              {'585af1b60098bf54b60bcab8c012ec1b': '58c0891900b4e2424cd148a3987bb899'},
              {'585af1b60098bf8e26b6b27d44c17e01': '58c08af100b0dba976bab7f6866ca206'}]

diz = {}
for t in testlabels:
    diz.update(t)

pd.Series(diz).to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... the csv writer only writes the first part to the file.

The `items` in `testlabels` are of type `dict`. But `csv.writerrow(...` expects a sequence-type.

> Python Documentation
>
> - [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)
> - [An asterisk ***** denotes iterable unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists)
> - [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)

---

The following example gets the `key, value` pair using `label.items()` and unpack it using `*` then pass it as `tuple` to `csv.writerrow(...` =>  **`(*label.items())`**

```
import io, csv

with io.StringIO() as outFile:
    wr = csv.writer(outFile)
    for label in testlabels:
        wr.writerow((*label.items()))

    print(outFile.getvalue())
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> 585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c,586556570100dac0eb73fcb231007126
> 585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8,588b9329004c4d7a5e27eb75b43c4c95
> 585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779,588be66300aba64caf9818cb4e194413
> ```

***Tested with Python 3.6***

Answer (score -1):

If you replace ':' with ',' the csv reader writes the output. If the ':' is not necessary, then use a comma. If you require ':,' then perhaps you can use string operations to replace it later. It is difficult to say without knowing more details.

```
import csv
#I changed only the first item from ':' to ','
testlabels = [{'585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c', 
'586556570100dac0eb73fcb231007126'}, 
{'585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8': '588b9329004c4d7a5e27eb75b43c4c95'}, 
{'585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779': '588be66300aba64caf9818cb4e194413'}, 
{'585ac23f005d7eab58953e03ae2e11e9': '588fe14100743d4472f8e18c474f057c'}, 
{'585ac23f005d7edd65e8c2bf4439dced': '58952dd60011750508739823983a1e33'}, 
{'585aca480065fa7ffb9e9b164bf03c82': '586557e201025a1d4818a0f5fe1b3051'}, 
{'585af09a0097e08d445c31bafc966c90': '585af0e300981a8493a172d6471b9154'}, 
{'585af1b60098bf1155b231a4d1c407f4': '58c0887600b478187ffbeb1d1db575d3'}, 
{'585af1b60098bf54b60bcab8c012ec1b': '58c0891900b4e2424cd148a3987bb899'}, 
{'585af1b60098bf8e26b6b27d44c17e01': '58c08af100b0dba976bab7f6866ca206'}]


resultFile = open("output.txt",'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile)

for item in testlabels:
    print(item)
    wr.writerow(item)
```

This gave me the output:

> 585abf5d005a8eb3c2d6e2851988cc0c,586556570100dac0eb73fcb231007126
>
> 585ac054005b72f16d9c6742858707c8
>
> 585ac054005b73207719baeda7b97779
>
> 585ac23f005d7eab58953e03ae2e11e9
>
> 585ac23f005d7edd65e8c2bf4439dced
>
> 585aca480065fa7ffb9e9b164bf03c82
>
> 585af09a0097e08d445c31bafc966c90
>
> 585af1b60098bf1155b231a4d1c407f4
>
> 585af1b60098bf54b60bcab8c012ec1b
>
> 585af1b60098bf8e26b6b27d44c17e01

Comment: this sounds like there will be two additional steps, adding commas first and then replacing it with colons later

Comment: Yeah, if you use this method then yes. This is simple though, just use string.replace(old, new, count). https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/ , if you really have to have colons for some reason.